# Drawing text on bitmap image

Tags: bmp

I'm looking for a C/C++ library (cross-platform, preferably) to draw text on a bmp image. 
I've already looked at EasyBMP, which has a font extension. However, I need to display Arial text - which is not available in EasyBMP.

Suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use [QPainter](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QPainter.html) from Qt framework. It's cross-platform and dual licensed(LGPL and commercial)